# How to change the textfield cursor colour in Cordova iOS project

Tags: html, ios, cordova, cursor, textfield

I have a blue background in my Cordova based iOS project due to which my cursor is not properly visible in iPhone device.So if anyone faced this please tell me How to change the textfield cursor color in Cordova iOS project or if any HTML attribute to change this tint color

textfield code in index.html:

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id='regFName' />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sujania - you just need to add the class "cursor" to your input type.

```
<input class="cursor" type="text" placeholder="First Name" id='regFName' />
```

Then the CSS will apply as you would expect!

Comment: the cursor remains still in blue color even after using in cursor in .css

Comment: Can you paste your CSS here?

Comment: I have used Rajesh Kumar Patel css answer

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:** Setting the `android:textCursorDrawable` attribute to `@null` should result in the use of `android:textColor` as the cursor color.

Attribute `textCursorDrawable` is available in API level 12 and higher

---

**Solution 2:** With iOS 7 you can simply change `tintColor` property of the `UITextField`. This will affect both the color of the text cursor and the text selection highlight color.

You can do this in code...

`textField.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]`;
... or in Interface Builder:

---

**Solution 3:** In your `EditText` properties, there is an attribute `android:textCursorDrawable`

Now set it to `@null` like,

`android:textCursorDrawable="@null"`

So now your `EditText` `Cursor` is same as your `EditText` `TextColor`.

---

**Solution 4:** Use an image along with CSS cursor property, I don't see any need of JavaScript here...

```
div {
   cursor: url(YOUR_IMAGE_URL), auto;
}
```

Comment: I need this solution of cordova based iPhone project, So is the solution 1 and solution 3 are for android?..Solution 2 is using objective c- I can't use this..I will try with solution 4 and let you know  the update

Comment: thank you for your efforts,No still the same blue color curdor

Comment: you need to take a small image like blink cursor with different color and use then.

<input type="text" class="mcursr" />

.mcursr{
 cursor: url(YOUR_IMAGE_URL), auto;
}

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of the cursor, write css for the cursor as follows:

```
.cursor {
        font-size: 12px;
        background-color: red;
        color: red;
        position: relative;
        opacity: 0.5;
       }
```

Comment: ..I m new to this Cordova HTML based tags..Can you  tell me where to use this code after editing in css file with index.html

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

for background-color user ur screen background color and for colore use white colore

```
<style>
 .cursor {
     font-size: 12px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.5;
   }
</style>
<input class="cursor " type="text" name="firstname">code here
```

hope this will work for u!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the css attribute `caret-color`, it's working for me.