# How to change the text input cursor color in Cordova IOS project

Tags: ios, cordova, text-cursor

I'm trying to change the text input cursor color in Cordova based mobile application on IOS 9.

Since the background is blue, cursor is almost invisible.

I have tried almost everything I could find but nothing seems to be working. I found the same question asked here

[How to change the textfield cursor colour in Cordova iOS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516400/how-to-change-the-textfield-cursor-colour-in-cordova-ios-project)

However none of the solutions on this page work.

I also tried solution on this page

https://gist.github.com/JoeKeikun/72718f5faaf518304024

This also does not work.

Any help will be appreciated, also if someone can confirm if it's due to a bug/feature related to IOS that would also be helpful.

Comment: Looks like the only way is to make cordova plugin for solutions proposed here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516400/how-to-change-the-textfield-cursor-colour-in-cordova-ios-project)

Comment: Which one ? Native solutions are not an option for my project as it's Cordova based.

Comment: There only cordova solution is to make cordova plugin that will encapsulate these native solutions and to use this plugin then. Currently, there are no such plugin yet.

Comment: That seems feasible, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Please share if you'll make it )

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: @ChandraSekharWalajapet, I didn't get a chance to do it, convinced customer that it wasn't possible :)

Comment: @11thdimension still struggling with it, seems to be not possible as of today, have to either change background or implement a blinking cursor on own